# Javascript Eventlistener unexpected else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, event-listener, unexpected-token

Could someone tell me what's wrong with this eventListener?
I keep getting unexpected token 'else' on it and don't get why.

JS:

```
hearts.forEach((span) => span.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  
  if( heart.classList.contains("liked")){
    $('.photoLikes').each(function() {
      sum = sum + (.35);
    } ) ;
    likeInfo.textContent=  (parseFloat(sum).toFixed(0)) ;
  } ; 
                
  else{
    $('.photoLikes').each(function() {
      sum = sum - (.35);
    } ) ;
    likeInfo.textContent=  (parseFloat(sum).toFixed(0)) ;
  } ; 
}
```

CodePen with full code(it's the eventlistener in comment at the end of the JS):

https://codepen.io/enukeron/pen/qBaZNbb?editors=1111

Comment: The `;` (semicolon) after the if-block doesn't belong there. Also, you didn't close the `(` (bracket) of your `forEacht()` and `addEventListener()` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put semicolons after if/else statements. They will break the expression, causing the `else` to not be attached to the `if`:

```js
hearts.forEach((span) =>
    span.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (heart.classList.contains("liked")) {
            $(".photoLikes").each(function () {
                sum = sum + 0.35;
            });
            likeInfo.textContent = parseFloat(sum).toFixed(0);
        } else {
            $(".photoLikes").each(function () {
                sum = sum - 0.35;
            });
            likeInfo.textContent = parseFloat(sum).toFixed(0);
        }
    })
);
```

You were also missing two close-parentheses at the end, which I added in.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. Now i have another problem: It works fine for the first element (adds 1 and removes 1), but only removes 1 for the others (https://codepen.io/enukeron/pen/qBaZNbb?editors=1111)

Answer (score 2):

looks like you have an extra semicolon after the if statement:

```
if () {
} ;
else {
} ;
```

Neither of those semicolons are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Two things here

- semicolon before `else` is not valid
- you missed 2 close parentheses for `span.addEventListener(` and `hearts.forEach(`

Modification should be

```
hearts.forEach((span) => span.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if( heart.classList.contains("liked")){
    $('.photoLikes').each(function() {
      sum = sum + (.35);
    } ) ;
    likeInfo.textContent=  (parseFloat(sum).toFixed(0)) ;
  } // <-----------

  else{
    $('.photoLikes').each(function() {
      sum = sum - (.35);
    } ) ;
    likeInfo.textContent=  (parseFloat(sum).toFixed(0)) ;
  }
})) // <-----------
```

Comment: "semicolon" instead of "comma" but otherwise good answer :)

Comment: The semicolon is not "redundant", it's just wrong.

Comment: @OskarGrosser I updated my answer, thanks